# Unreachable code detected in C# Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docx

Hi I am having an issue with some code in my controller. I want to be able to save a generated Word document on the server with this code but it is giving me a 'Unreachable Code Detected' error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult STAWordGen2(UserLogon model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.ApplicantID, model.UserPassword))
            {

                FormsService.SignIn(model.ApplicantID, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl((returnUrl)))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Test");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["alert"] = "Login Failed.  The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
                return View();
            }

            string filename = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/cvs/worddoc/test.docx");
            var doc = DocX.Create(filename);
            string headLine = "Test fingers crossed";
            doc.InsertParagraph(headLine);
            doc.Save();

        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: What is the context of this code?

Comment: There isn't enough information about this code, and the surrounding code, to make any useful suggestions. This code as written looks fine, from an execution path point-of-view.

Comment: Apologies this is my first post. It is basically an actionresult which when executed should run the above code. I have edited the post to show all the code, cheers for looking.

Comment: @vcsjones - that's wrong, it isn't fine. His conditional statements early on in the method `return` too early. 'Too early' given the fact there is code for lines after that.

Comment: @DeeMac The question has [been edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24826874/revisions) since I made that comment. Look at the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string filename = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/cvs/worddoc/test.docx");
var doc = DocX.Create(filename);
string headLine = "Test fingers crossed";
doc.InsertParagraph(headLine);
doc.Save();
```

Before this part of your code, you have if-else statements which return. Your code will not be reached because of the else statement. Either it is **if** or **else**, and they return...

Comment: Thank you folks for your comments, I will play around with it and see if I can get it to work, cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow through all of the different potential branches, you'll find that you're hitting a `return` in every case before getting to this line:

```
string filename = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/cvs/worddoc/test.docx");
```

You'll have to rethink your if/else/return logic.